# Special characters \0 {NUL} in Java

Tags: java, string, null-terminated

How to replace \0 (NUL) in the String?

```
String b = "2012yyyy06mm";               // sth what i want
String c = "2\0\0\0012yyyy06mm";
String d = c.replaceAll("\\\\0", "");    // not work
String e = d.replace("\0", "");          // er, the same
System.out.println(c+"\n"+d+"\n"+e);

String bb = "2012yyyy06mm";
System.out.println(b.length() + " > " +bb.length());
```

The above code will print 12 > 11 in console. Oops, What happened?

```
String e = c.replace("\0", "");
System.out.println(e);      // just print 2(a bad character)2yyyy06mm
```

Answer (score 15):

Your string `"2\0\0\0012yyyy06mm"` does not start `2 {NUL} {NUL} {NUL} 0 1 2`, but instead contains `2 {NUL} {NUL} {SOH} 2`.

The `\001` is treated as a single ASCII 1 character (`SOH`) and not as a `NUL` followed by `1 2`.

The result is that only two characters are being removed, not three.

I don't think there's any way to represent digits following an abbreviated [octal escape](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6) other than by breaking the string apart:

```
String c = "2" + "\0\0\0" + "012yyyy06mm";
```

or alternately, specify all three digits in the (last) octal escape such that the following digits are not interpreted as being part of the octal escape:

```
String c = "2\000\000\000012yyyy06mm";
```

Once you've done that, replacing `"\0"` as per your line:

```
String e = c.replace("\0", "");
```

will work correctly.

Comment: Hi, tls for help.   String c = "2\0\0\0012yyyy06mm";
  String e = c.replace("\0", "");
  System.out.println(e);     // just print 22yyyy06mm

Comment: @user1900556 yes, because the `\001` still embedded therein (between the two "2"s) is invisible.  The whole point is that the string `c` that you have doesn't contain what you think it does.

Comment: @user1900556 I showed you - either fully pad your octal escapes to three digits, or break the string apart.  Either way, you've got to fix the assignment of `c` - the `.replace("\0", ...)` is fine.

Comment: @user1900556 the `\001` is *one character*, not 2, 3 or 4, it can also be written as `\u0001` which is still one character. Note: space can be written as `\040` or `\u0020` but it is always one character.  You cannot replace just part of the character, and you cannot determine how it was defined either.