# How to replace EOT character

Tags: java

This is my problem.

I import data from my back-office system using a servlet and save the data to my SQL Server. In the data there is the EOT character (end of transmission).

When I view the record in my sql server management studio I see it like this image below:

[image]

When i copy/paste the text in Notepad++ i get this:

[image]

Its clear to me that in my db I have the EOT character.

How can i replace this character in my front-end to show something like `<br/>`?

I tried `str.replace("\0","<br/>")` mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857726/special-characters-0-nul-in-java) but no luck.

Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: Is the hex value for this really 0 ? What does Notepad++ show in hex mode ?  Have you tried using two or even more backslashes ? Please remember that you might need up to four backslashes because of multiple escaping.

Comment: ahhhh , i got it.... should actually use `.replace("\4", "<br/>")` , now it works, thats the ASCII Decimal code fot EOT

Comment: the post linked state about NUL, not EOT

Comment: @Hacketo yes you are right, that was my bad

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is to use `.replace("\4", "<br/>")` , where the `4` after the `\` is the Decimal Value of EOT in the ASCII table

```
   Oct   Dec   Hex   Char                        Oct   Dec   Hex   Char
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   000   0     00    NUL '\0'                    100   64    40    @
   001   1     01    SOH (start of heading)      101   65    41    A
   002   2     02    STX (start of text)         102   66    42    B
   003   3     03    ETX (end of text)           103   67    43    C
   004   4     04    EOT (end of transmission)   104   68    44    D
   005   5     05    ENQ (enquiry)               105   69    45    E
   006   6     06    ACK (acknowledge)           106   70    46    F
   007   7     07    BEL '\a' (bell)             107   71    47    G
   010   8     08    BS  '\b' (backspace)        110   72    48    H
   011   9     09    HT  '\t' (horizontal tab)   111   73    49    I
   012   10    0A    LF  '\n' (new line)         112   74    4A    J
   013   11    0B    VT  '\v' (vertical tab)     113   75    4B    K
   014   12    0C    FF  '\f' (form feed)        114   76    4C    L
   015   13    0D    CR  '\r' (carriage ret)     115   77    4D    M
   016   14    0E    SO  (shift out)             116   78    4E    N
   017   15    0F    SI  (shift in)              117   79    4F    O
   020   16    10    DLE (data link escape)      120   80    50    P
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways I can think of to do this. The brute-force method would be to create a method that sanitizes the String you got; perhaps by turning the String into a collection of chars that you scan to remove this and any other chars you don't want, and return a new String.

Without looking, I assume that there are libraries out there that can be used to sanitize Strings. I assume Guava and the Apache Java libraries have methods that can sanitize Strings in this manner.

The gotcha is knowing if and when you can treat this String *essentially* as a series of bytes and when you cannot. I'd probably reach for a hex editor or even POSIX `od` command to look harder at the actual bytes of the data you are sanitizing.